# Bootstrap Prepend Button to Dynamic Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm updating some content on a website running Bootstrap 2.0.4 (I know it's dated but don't have the time to update it yet!).

I'm trying to prepend a button on to an input element. When the button is clicked I'm adding another button dynamically below it using jquery, I need this also to have the button prepended.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ltfhx75/6/), would appreciate any help.

HTML

```
<div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
  <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-fields hide">
  <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".add-more").click(function() {
     var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
     $(".after-add-more").after(html);
   });
   $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
     $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
   });
 });
```

Comment: You can use [jQuery prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: Do you want to provide an answer? Thanks

Comment: It will be helpful if you share the screenshot. What is the existing output and what you are trying to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check updated snippet below....

```js
 $(".add-more").click(function() {
   var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
   $(".after-add-more").before(html);
 });
 $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
   $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
 });
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
  <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-fields hide">
  <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the html should be added only once.

Comment: this doesn't achieve what I was asking? Thanks though